# PF Rules to Block All But Accesses to VPN and LAN

Tags: security, firewall, vpn, pf, lan

The rule set to block all outgoing connections except for VPN access could be like this:

```
block drop all
pass on lo0
pass on utun0
pass out proto udp from any to xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt port pppp
```

This works fine. However, I “forgot” that I still want to have access to the LAN as well. I thought then I could simply add these rules “somewhere”, but I don't know really where… I know the order is important though.

```
pass in on en4 from 192.168.0.0/24 to any
pass out on en4 from any to 192.168.0.0/24
```

No success… I’m pretty sure I’ve got something right, but I don’t know the exact layout.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that if you tried something like this you might have better luck:

```
block drop all
pass on lo0
pass on utun0
pass out proto udp from any to xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt port pppp
pass in  on en4 from 192.168.0.0/24
pass out on en4 to   192.168.0.0/24
```

**NOTE:** Please note that I do not have a PF firewall to confirm these work.

#### References

- [Example PF Rules](http://node.mu/2005/11/25/example-pf-rules/)
- [OpenBSD PF - Packet Filtering](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html#quick)